# Golang weird behavior when converting float to int

Tags: go, math, integer

I have the following code in golang:

```
var fnum float32 = 99999999;
var inum int32 = int32(fnum);
fmt.Println(inum); // This prints out 100000000
```

Why is it that 99999999 is changed to 100000000?
I don't think I went over the limits of both float32 and int32, so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: `float32` has 6 (or 7) significant digits of precision, which means anything above that could be lost. It's not Go-specific, every language that implements IEEE754 would behave the same.

Comment: 32 bit float has 24 bits of mantisa giving you up to `16777216` of precise integers your `99999999` is bigger so rounding occurs. However its weird as while casting to int rounding down is more common ...

Comment: @Spektre it's not "rounded" when casted to int, but during `var fnum float32 = 99999999;` assignment. When `int32(fnum)` happens - the precision has already been lost.

Comment: @zerkms the "casting to int" occurs while conversion of `99999999` into mantissa part of `float`  as mantissa is 24 bit integer !!! So yes its occurring in the line `var fnum float32 = 99999999;` in compile time (unless you got interpreting environment) the mantissa should hold `12499999` (as that is 24 bit most significant bits of `99999999`)  however you claim your number is `100000000` which is weird but may be its just rounding during printing try to print full precision like force to print 10 decimal places after `.` and you should see something like `9999999?.??????????`

Comment: @Spektre `float32` cannot represent `99999999`. `100000000` is the closest representible value (1 apart). https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=057057057057057057057057 Mantissa `12499999` results to `9.9999992E7` (7 apart) https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=4CBEBC1F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [(IEEE 754) 32-bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) represents real values in the form

```txt
value = (−1)^sign × 2^e × (1 + 2^−1 b[22] + 2^−2 b[21] + ... + 2^−23 b[0])
```

where "e" is an integer exponent between −126 to +127 and "b[22], ..., b[0]" make up the bits of the significand.

Clearly, this representation is limited, not all real numbers can be expressed exactly. When it comes to integers, the smallest integer that cannot be represented exactly as float32 is 2^24 + 1 = 16777217. Particularly at this point the exponent factor is 2^24, but with the smallest significand term being 2^−23 b[0], odd integers (value % 2) ≠ 0 above 2^24 are not exactly representable.

Similarly for the value 99999999, the exponent factor is 2^26, and integers above 2^26 with (value % 8) ≠ 0 are not exactly representable. The closest representable float32 values to 99999999 are 99999992 and 100000000.